# Get Lock and ID atomically

Tags: mysql, locking

I am using MySQL for a distributed locking mechanism. It works pretty great however I have one very small race condition that I have never hit but am curious if I have other options to avoid it.

Currently in my code I call GET_LOCK and then right after it I call IS_USED_LOCK to get the ID of connection holding the lock. This is needed so I can watch for it to change and signal other stuff to happen. However it is seemingly possibly for me to call GET_LOCK get the lock and then lose it in the milliseconds before calling IS_USED_LOCK.

Do I have any option to atomically call GET_LOCK and get the lock ID?

UPDATE:

I didn't know `SELECT GET_LOCK('test/lock', 10), IS_USED_LOCK('test/lock');` was possible but not sure if internally this is actually atomic.

Comment: `IS_USED_LOCK()` doesn't return the lock id, it returns session id for the holder of the lock.

Comment: Yes sorry that is what I meant, thanks for adding the tag!